# Degree of a function of a quaternion variable

Tags: differential-geometry, quaternions

I have the quaternions $q = x_0 + ix_1 + jx_2 + kx_3$ where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $i,j,k$ satisfy the relations $$ i^2=j^2=k^2 = -1, \hspace{0.3cm} ij=-ji=k,\hspace{0.3cm}  jk=-kj=i,\hspace{0.3cm}  ki=-ik=j$$
I also have that $f(q) =q^2$ defines a smooth map from $\mathbb{R}^4 \cup \{\infty\} \cong S^4$ to itself.

I have to find the degree of f. Can someone help me ?

Comment: How did you define degree?

Comment: This seems to be very similar to the complex number case where $\,f(z):=z^2\,$ has degree $2$ at $\,z=0\,$ and also at $\,z=\infty.\,$ This generalizes to the degree $\,n\,$ case of $\,f(z):=z^n.$

Comment: @Somos is this related to the definition of winding number ?

Comment: @Keshav I just studed how to define the degree of a smooth map $f: M \rightarrow N$ between manifolds as $deg f = \int_M f^{*} \omega_N$, where $\omega$ is a n-form and then the notions of winding and linking number.